# How to get a list of all attributes(either set or not set) that are applicable for a specific tag in HTML?

Tags: html, attributes, tags

How to get a list of all attributes(either set or not set) that are applicable for a specific tag in HTML?
For example, to get a list of all attributes that are applicable for  tag...
Is JS method to do so?

Following are my imaginary JS methods describing my requirement...

**document.getAllApplicableAttributesForTag('a');**

OR

**element = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];**

**element.getAllApplicableAttributes();**

Is there any valid way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.attributes` to get a list of all attributes.

or simply use `getAttributes()` from [hotdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hotdom) library to get all attributes in a proper format with more options.

```js
const a = dom.select('a');

dom.getAttributes(a);
```

above code will return all attributes of the anchor tag.

```js
[
  {attr: "href", value: "#"},
  {attr: "title", value: "foo"}
]
```